# Whole cshtml page doesn't work after an action is made ( all the buttons and fields don't work)

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I have a working system that has a cshtml page where you can add new items. These items are related to a tree of items, and if I don't set a specific item to add on, it would add directly to the root.
It is kinda hard to explain, but the main thing is that whenever I add an item directly to the root(not being specific), it works fine. However, whenever I click on a specific item and add a new item to be its child, the proccess works fine and the item is added, but after that the whole page doesn't work. At all. All the fields, buttons, anything. The only way to solve is to refresh the page.

The page is made in cshtml with jquery.

I wanted to know if any of you have ever been in to a situation like this and if you did, how'd you manage to solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're saying when you click a button, some javascript is supposed to fire, but it doesn't.  Hit F12 in Chrome and go to Console.  Tell me what it says.

Comment: Okay.. so I actually couldn't force the error(sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't), but I manage to get the 404 error on http://localhost:49430/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.map

And when I meant "nothing works", I meant that it seems they are unusable, uneditable, unclickable, something like this.

Comment: You have to find out when it works and when it doesn't.  If it's seems random, you'll have to try to dig deeper.  Look at the network panel to see what scripts are loaded and which aren't.  Right click the controls  and inspect them to see why they are disabled.